# What does happen with webpack when entry point is not defined?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, entry-point

What does happen when entry point is not defined in webpack configuration? Which files should be processed by webpack in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not defined and the version you are using is  `>= webpack v4`, it by default points to [`./src/`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) which will take in consideration the index file inside `src`.

When `./src/index` does not exist, webpack throws an error.

Comment: Thanks! What about webpack < v4? Does webpack immediately throw an error?

Comment: Probably, i haven't tested and its being so much time i don't use v3.